# JS if statement and basic write operations not working in Vue3/Vite composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

Good day,
i want to write data into firebase realtime database and later maybe firestore, and took this script from the official documentation

```
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";

function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
  const db = getDatabase();
  set(ref(db, 'users/' + userId), {
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
}
```

Does not work in script setup composition even after wrapping the function into if statement

Component is

```
<script setup>
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";

const database = getDatabase();

function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
    if (event) {
      const db = getDatabase();
      set(ref(db, 'users/' + userId), {
        username: name,
        email: email,
        profile_picture : imageUrl
      });
  }
}
</script>

<template>
<form action="#" v-on:submit.prevent="Submit">
    <v-container class="text-left"><h4>Account bearbeiten</h4>

                        <v-text-field label="Name" id="name" hide-details="auto" />

                        <v-text-field label="Email" id="email" hide-details="auto" />

    <v-btn flat density="compact" @click.prevent="writeUserData">Speichern</v-btn>
    </v-container>
</form>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.v-container { max-width:500pt;  margin: 5px 0; }
</style>
```

Comment: where are you calling this function from . you need to provide the full vue component, any errors that are occuring in the console ?

Comment: from the page a user gets routed to after login, which works and has working delete script. authorisation infrastructure seems to work based on scripts from the documentation.

Comment: any errors in the console of your browser... ?

Comment: Navigation error
      tabId: 46
      url: about:blank
      error: Error code 2152398850 utils.js:188:15
Navigation error
      tabId: 46
      url: the database server url
      error: Error code 2152398850

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have firebase.ts or firebase.js file in the root of the directory where you have setup the config to connect to firebase project that you have created on firebase console like explained [here](https://softauthor.com/add-firebase-to-vuejs/). if you have done that, then the only change that needs to be done in your code is the following,

you are not passing any values to your function for it to write the data. It does not know what is a userId, name, email, imageUrl etc..

you need to define the name, email as reactive variables

```
<script setup>
import { getDatabase, ref as dbref, set } from "firebase/database";
import { ref } from "vue";

const database = getDatabase();
const name = ref(name)
const email = ref(email)
const userId = 'testuserid'
const imageUrl = 'testurl'

function writeUserData(name, email) {
      const db = getDatabase();
      set(dbref(db, 'users/' + userId), {
        username: name.value,
        email: email.value,
      });
}
</script>
```

In the template, link the refs to the filed through v-model. basically you are binding the values of your reactive variables to the fields so that when you type values the values are updated.

```
<template>
<form action="#" v-on:submit.prevent="Submit">
    <v-container class="text-left"><h4>Account bearbeiten</h4>

                        <v-text-field v-model="name" label="Name" id="name" hide-details="auto" />

                        <v-text-field v-model="email" label="Email" id="email" hide-details="auto" />

    <v-btn flat density="compact" @click.prevent="writeUserData">Speichern</v-btn>
    </v-container>
</form>
</template>
```

Now you should be see the data getting updated, if you have properly configured firebase in your project.

Comment: i am not sure what you are refering to as scripts deleting data .... regarding userId, the example, it is an example...for example when you signup a user, you will get a uid, and you can use that uid as a userId to write your document. i am not sure again what you mean by does not work with constructors...

Comment: The ref import via Vue does not work, because it is already once existent, in {getDatabase, ref, set } from 'firebase/database'. Vue regards that as wrong yet needs that to make the constructors reactive.

Comment: ah..you are right there is a name clash between firebase's ref and vue's ref. i have update the imports. you can alias the firebase ref to dbref for example.

Comment: Thank. That helpd a lot. I was void of hlp bcause of so many unity coders not helping.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with. Thanks. It renders the UID since i saw that was a quest. Declaring constructors in ref, reactive is impossible without setting ref as some other instancy, or ref as some other instancy in vue import.

```
<script setup>
import { getDatabase, ref as dbref, set } from "firebase/database";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";

    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    const userId = user.uid;
    const mail = user.email;
    const ident = user.name;
    alert(userId);
    const database = getDatabase();
    const name = ref(ident);
                const email = ref(mail);
    /* ----------------- */

function writeUserData(userId, name, email) {
  const db = getDatabase();
  set(dbref(db, 'users/' + userId), {
        username: name.value,
        email: email.value
  });
}
</script>

<template>
<form action="#" v-on:submit.prevent="writeUserData">
    <v-container class="text-left"><h4>Account bearbeiten</h4>

                        <v-text-field v-model="name" label="Name" id="name" hide-details="auto" />

                        <v-text-field v-model="email" label="Email" id="email" hide-details="auto" />

    <v-btn flat density="compact" @click.prevent="writeUserData">Speichern</v-btn>
    </v-container>
</form>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.v-container { max-width:500pt;  margin: 5px 0; }
</style>
```

It works now. But it still does not populate the server with data.

These are the rules i set:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
<script setup>
import { getDatabase, ref as dbref, set } from "firebase/database";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";
import "firebase/database";

    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    const userId = user.uid;
    const mail = user.email;
    const ident = user.name;
    const database = getDatabase();
    const name = ref(ident);
    const email = ref(mail);

function writeUserData(e) {
  const db = getDatabase();
  set(dbref(db, 'users/' + userId), {
        username: name.value,
        email: email.value
  });
}
</script>

<template>
    <form action="#" v-on:submit.prevent="writeUserData">
        <v-container class="text-left"><h4>Account bearbeiten</h4>
    
            <v-text-field v-model="name" label="Name" id="name" hide-details="auto" />
            
            <v-text-field v-model="email" label="Email" id="email" hide-details="auto" />
    
        <v-btn flat density="compact" id="test" @click.prevent="writeUserData">Speichern</v-btn>
        </v-container>
    </form>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.v-container { max-width:500pt;  margin: 5px 0; }
</style>
```

It now works since i changed the function to (e). This seems inspired on simpler math, like image manipulation techniques in javascript, like simple things in code, that later looks more philosopher.

Thx, thanks.

It adds now the data.

[Firebase documentation inspired data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7ne8.png)